# Can I document a VOR check with a photo to comply with 91.171(d)?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, vor

I'm interested in understanding the limits of what it means to "sign" a record. While enroute for any meaningful length of time, I try to tune two VOR's and I take a photo of the G1000 NXi on my phone to ensure I always have a current VOR check. This photo contains metadata with the date and place the photo was taken, and the photo details the bearing error. The only thing i'm missing for this photo the be the "other document" I require and to avoid having to write out a random slip of paper to that will satisfy the requirements for [91.171(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=se14.2.91_1171&rgn=div8) is the signature.

I understand this signature is to certify that this information is factual and that it really took place and that the legal definition of a signature has evolved a lot over the past few decades. Clearly it doesn't matter that I infer the intent of the signature portion of the rule to be to ensure that no one lies about performing the VOR test.

- Is my photo sufficient because it shows that the test was actually performed?
- Should I edit my photo and scribble a "signature" on it?
- Maybe a `live photo` with a "voice signature" would work?
- Or do I need to keep writing on little scraps of paper to cover myself?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: The only time this will ever come up is in an enforcement action.  I think you would meet the intent of the regulation by the picture especially if the date and time are included in the picture somehow.

Comment: Date, time and even GPS coordinates can be (and are, by default) stored in the EXIF data added to most every digital picture taken. Unfortunately, it's quite easy to [edit EXIF data](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=edit+exif+data&ia=web), so the FAA _might_ question you on it.